# Exchange 2007 backup in Windows 2008

Tags: backup, exchange

Does anyone know of any free/low cost tools which will backup Exchange 2007 on Windows 2008 to a portable hard drive?

I am using the built in Windows backup but would like a second backup just in case.

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the problem you are solving here? Do you have a reason not to trust the backups currently being taken? Is there a reason why running the backup routine twice to different sources wouldn't be acceptable, for example?

To do a *proper* Exchange backup, you need an *exchange aware* backup tool. Those generally are not cheap.

Comment: In Windows Server 2003 it was free, so not sure why you don't think they are expensive. In Windows Server 2008 (and exchange 2007) they took away the option of backing up via NTBACKUP forcing you to buy expensive solutions when free solutions worked fine.

Comment: Stephen, "Not cheap" which is what I said, *does* mean "expensive".

Comment: I should add that yes, I was shocked myself that Microsoft took out their own backup method for Exchange 2007. It seems absurd to have a system like that with no easy "built in" backup method; with MS SQL Server you can backup DBs to files, for example.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft took away the brick level backup from Windows Server 2008, so basically all you can do is to do a VSS snapshot and backup the source quenced mailbox.

I have tried using Carbonite Online backup, and it backed up a VSS Mail Database without a problem, but its not free, just $5 a month.

Comment: Windows Backup has *never* supported Brick Level Backup of the mail database, so not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong, it did in Windows Server 2003 with Exchange extensions installed

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Exchange-2003-Backup-Restore-NTBACKUP.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm not wrong, I think your definitions are mixed up. "Brick Level Backup" refers to backing up the mail stores in such a way as to allow restore of individual mailboxes without restoring the entire mail store. (see http://www.petri.co.il/brick_level_backup_of_mailboxes_by_using_exmerge.htm ) and if you think that's wrong google "Brick Level Backups" and notice how its defined by all the people who actually sell Brick Level Backup products.

This has *never* been possible with the Exchange/NTBackup combo, mostly because Microsoft don't recommend it as "best practice".